# How should I make a constant visible between multiple projects?

Tags: vb6, constants, global

I have one project which provides a service to the others, and the return value of the method that provides this service is String.  Within that project, I use some named constants to represent special out of band values that are returned in lieu of expected or recoverable errors, otherwise the service returns an XML string.

Something like the following:

```
' modService.bas
const SERVICE_BADARG as String = "Unsupported argument."
const SERVICE_TOOMANY as String = "Too many Foos."

' cServiceProvider.cls
Private Function GetXMLString() as String
' generate and return XML string holding all sorts of generic stuff
End Function

Public Function PerformService(argument as String) as String
' do some stuff
If (some_condition = true) Then
    PerformService = SERVICE_BADARG
Else If (some_other_condition = true) Then
    PerformService = SERVICE_TOOMANY
Else
    PerformService = GetXMLString()
```

I'd like to be able, from other projects, be able to get at these constants without redundantly defining them.  If possible, I'd also like to avoid putting them in the class (where they will be duplicated unnecessarily) and to avoid making a property for each one.

They are all constants, none of them ever change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, VB gives you no mechanism of embedding constants into DLLs for compile-time use. You would have to return properties, as you said you didn't want to do.

I would definitely use the BAS route, unless there is a reason against it. An alternative to this would be to create a type library, and define the string constants in there. To do this, you will have to learn ODL, and use the MkTypeLib.exe program which comes with VB6. Or, if you somehow have access to "Advanced Visual Basic 6.0" by Matt Curland, there is a tool which allows you to create type libraries.

Comment: Properties is probably the best way.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just define the constants in a `CONSTANTS.BAS` module, and then include that in each project? That way, to VB it would look like the definitions were duplicated, but from your perspective as a developer and a maintenance programmer, the definitions would all be collected in a single place?

Another option would be to create a DLL that defined the constants, but that would make using the values of those constants more costly in all of your code because rather than being compiled directly into the object code, they would have to be retrieved from a call to an external DLL. That seems like overkill for something that is truly constant.

Consider that a "constant" value is not necessarily the same thing as a "read-only" value. A constant value, like pi, will *never change*, so there is really not much to be lost by duplicating those values. You won't ever need to go back in and change them. Read-only values (like your error message strings) might change, so they're not really constants. It might make sense to place those into a DLL. Especially since performance isn't all that critical when all you're trying to do is shown an error message.

Comment: At this point everything is a giant hodgepodge of DLLs anyway and there are so many projects that it wouldn't be worth the effort of duplicating all of this data.  The DLL solution was more or less what I was aiming for.  How would I accomplish it?

Comment: For the record, this particular service is only going to be used by  about 6 or 7 projects.  However, I plan to try to centralize configuration later.  settings are stored in a kind of jumbled mess of config files and registry keys, and I've already counted several different registry and file editing modules, each with slightly different features, visibility, and code smells. Centralizing that could touch many, many projects and duplicating the same constants 50 times will cause displeasure.  As an aside, I'm the intern and my codebase is a jungle. large architectural changes are not possible.

Comment: @Wug The ability to create ActiveX DLLs is built in out of the box. To compile other types of DLLs, you need to do a bit more work. I'd drop into C++ to do it, but that's probably not an option for most VB devs. I would recommend looking into [vbAdvance](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/vbAdvance/). But your second comment does make a good point—is it really worth touching an enormous number of files just to put all the constants in a single place? Lots of people would probably tell you not to waste too much time refactoring VB 6 code, but instead to focus that energy on migration. Worth considering.

Comment: Unfortunately, no it's not.  All of the code would definitely benefit from a rewrite, but its simply not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case anyone is still wondering...
try this pattern:

```
Public Function SERVICE_BADARG() As String
    SERVICE_BADARG = "Unsupported argument."
End Function
Public Function SERVICE_TOOMANY() As String
    SERVICE_TOOMANY = "Too many Foos."
End Function
```

Or more compactly with colons to put stuff on the same line:

```
Public Function SERVICE_BADARG() As String: SERVICE_BADARG = "Unsupported argument.": End Function
Public Function SERVICE_TOOMANY() As String: SERVICE_TOOMANY = "Too many Foos.": End Function
```

You could see a constant as a function without arguments. The advantage is that a function can be public, so you don't have to create a DLL. It also gets around only being able to declare them before other functions. VB6 allows you to hide the brackets:

```
x = "error: " & SERVICE_TOOMANY

Select Case y
    Case SERVICE_BADARG
        z = "error: y is a bad arg"
    Case SERVICE_TOOMANY
        z = "error: y is too many"
End Select
```

The disadvantage is a little overhead, but this is typically negligible